# Execute sed command in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I want to execute this comand in bash scripting.

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
line=39;
d=d; ## For delete line
`echo "sed '$line$d' /etc/passwd"`;
```

But when I execute, I got this error:

```
sed: -e expresion #1, character 1: unknow command <<'>>
```

I tried with `echo "sed \'$line$d\' /etc/passwd"`;

But same problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to insure when calling your variables that you do not prevent expansion by `single-quoting` them. Now it is OK to use `single-quotes` **within** `double-quotes`, but be mindful. Also, though not required, when putting two variables back-to-back, it is better to use braces to insure against ambiguity. That said, your `sed` command from a script works fine as:

```
sed -e "${line}${d}" /etc/passwd
```

Which will output `/etc/passwd` to `stdout` minus line `$line`. To edit `/etc/passwd` in place, use `sed -i`

Comment: I don't think `d` should be expanded, he wants to remove using `sed` I believe. Right now there isn't even a `sed` command... The problem, it seems to me, was that he was trying to end the variable with a dollar instead of encapsulating it with curly braces.

Comment: Look at the code in `pastebin` immediately before the call it does `d=d`

Comment: Yes I overlooked that part, my bad. This is definitely the better answer :)

Comment: Your solution was perfect David C. Rankin! Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

To delete line 39 simply do:

```
#!/bin/bash
line=39;
sed -i "${line}d" /etc/passwd
```

Sed will take the second argument as input file and the first as a command. The extra flag `-i` will allow you to redirect the output immediately to the input file. Note that this is not the same as `sed 'command' file > file` as this will result in an empty file.

I also advise executing `man sed` in your shell.

Comment: delete `line 39` from where? output to `stdout`? or in `/etc/passwd`?

Comment: `/etc/passwd`is the input file, check his code in the pastebin.

Comment: I did, sed `foo` /etc/password only operates on `cat /etc/passwd`. You must include `-i` for `edit in place`.

Comment: You're right, I was being sloppy! Consider my answer revoked!! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

# delete line 39 by editing inline via sed;
sed -i '39d' /etc/passwd
```

Keep it simple and add the comment if you want remember the sed action

Comment: The problem is that I dont know the line, I get line number counting in a for, and comparing names.

Comment: in this case, the @ShellFish reply is fine